# What's the Android gradle plugin version for Android Studio 2 Beta in canary channel?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I got this message in Android Studio 2 Preview 9 about Android Studio 2.0 Beta being available in the canary channel.

[image]

But after updating, I'm getting a message saying

`2.0.0-alpha9 is an old preview version of the Android plugin; please update to the latest version.`

Does anyone know what the latest version of the Android plugin is?  I tried `2.0.0-Beta` and `2.0.0-beta`, but that didn't work.

[jcenter](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/view) doesn't appear to have a more recent version than `2.0.0-alpha9`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs to be `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta1'`

This is what Android Studio updated the value to be after using the "Fix plugin version and sync project" option in the below dialog that appeared after applying the update:

[image]

As a side note good to see Android Studio 2.0 has been moved to Beta!

EDIT:

Well that did not take long for Beta 2 to appear. Since I only answered this yesterday I'll update the answer in case somebody else stumbles across it.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta2'
```

Comment: agreed! i wasn't expecting it to be in beta so soon.  how did you find out the version?

Comment: @Julian When I updated Android Studio suggested it :P

Comment: I updated the answer with an image of what popped up.